# AND OR search syntax in lucene

Tags: java, netbeans, lucene

I am using Lucene. I have three columns which are

```
DocId - TermID - TermFrequency
 1    -   004  -      667
 2    -   005  -      558
```

If i use mysql then query for AND operation is

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DocId='1' AND TermId='004'
```

How can i write above query in Lucene using JAVA. For one column search code i am using is

```
Query query = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_35,"TermID", analyzer).parse("004");
```

How can i use AND operation in QueryParser ??

Comment: Just so you know, there is also another way of creating logical queries using `BooleanQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Terms can be grouped with the `AND` keyword like so:

```
Query query = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_35,"TermID", analyzer).parse("004 AND DocId:1");
```

Note that you don't need to qualify the field for your `"004"` term because you've set `"TermId"` as the default field.

You should read [the manual](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/queryparsersyntax.html) on the query syntax...it's pretty expressive.

Comment: The `QueryParser`'s second parameter is the default field.  If a term doesn't have the `fieldName:` qualifier, then it's automatically set to the default.  So in the code sample above, your query would actually be parsed to `"TermId:004 AND DocId:1"` thanks to this default.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  If my answer helped, I would appreciate it if you marked it as accepted.  Thanks!